# Are Red and Green somehow more dominant than Blue (RGB)?

Tags: opengl, colors, shader, rgb

In OpenGL, I made a sphere and gave every Fragment the Color of its normalized position. The sphere is right at the origin so the sphere should be covered with smooth color gradients between red, green, and blue, while on every axis, the color is pure(x - red, y - green, z - blue).

---

but not like I expected i see this shape when i look down the Z/Blue Axis

[image]

---

I played around a little and compared the gradients between the different colors

---

[image]
(looking down the x axis with zero red color)

In this image, it looks like the Green color is somehow more dominant than the blue, as if it was sprayed on top of it. Also the Blue seems to be deminished by the black.

---

[image]
(looking down the y axis with zero green color)
In this image there seems to be a smoother gradient but i´d still say there is more red than blue in the image but this might be my individual perception and the picture is not perfectly symmetrical aswell.

---

[image]
(looking down the z axis with zero blue color)

To me it looks like Green and Red are more dominant than blue for some reason.

But what originally brought up this question is the weird hard gradient i got (first image). I dont think it is a bug in my shaders, because i never treat any color individually.

What could cause this behaviour?

PS: I have not implemented alpha yet and i am not using alpha anywhere in my shader (where i use a vec4 for color, the 4th component is always 1.0)

Comment: There is a lot of jpg artifacts in your images - I can't see the shape you're describing.

Comment: In the first image there are 4 edges during the gradients of red and green. i can see a cross pretty clearly. It´s not a big issue but i was just interested where this might come from. Might just be my hardware or software configuration which causes this.

Comment: Yes, but it's not why you see what you see. So for the purpose of your question: No. You have a bug in the z-axis calculations, and we can't pin-point it without seeing the code.

Comment: http://textuploader.com/ddnc1
These are my shaders. I am now also having trouble with the specular lighting. it seems like the normals are not being interpolated, because i have vertex artifacts on the sphere, even though the normals are smooth.